# Cannot display an image when reading from the local machine

Tags: javascript, asp.net

On my web page I'm trying to load an image to asp image control using Javascript, I'm setting the src to image control in the correct way but the image is not been load.

```
<div class="rightPane">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Preview</legend>
                <img id="pvwImage" alt="" class="previmage" />
            </fieldset>
        </div>


    function OnClientItemSelected(sender, args) {


        var pvwImage = $telerik.$("#pvwImage");
        var imageSrc = args.get_path();
        if (imageSrc.match(/\.(gif|jpg)$/gi)) {

            pvwImage.src = imageSrc;
            $("#pvwImage").attr("src", pvwImage.src);
            //pvwImage.style.display = "";
            document.getElementById("pvwImage").style.display = "block";
            pvwImage.alt = imageSrc.substring(imageSrc.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        }

        else {

            pvwImage.style.display = "none";

        }


    }
```

That's my src path: C:/Inetpubb/IRPictures/SSC/2013/8/IR-9897/9897(2).jpg

what can be the problem?

By the way if I'm changing the path to let's say:
http://img.s-msn.com/tenant/amp/entityid/BBdrGbm.img?h=194&w=300&m=6&q=60&u=t&o=t&l=f&x=1036&y=497

it's working fine.

Comment: `C:` is not a webserver, it doesn't serve static content, it's your local hard drive ?

Comment: Yes C: is my local hard drive

Comment: And what makes you think you can load images from your local computer directly into a website ?

Comment: You can't simply point try loading an image from `C:/Inetpubb/IRPictures/SSC/2013/8/IR-9897/9897(2).jpg` Unless every user has that exact file on their local computer of course ;)

Comment: what is the solution??

Comment: It should work like that: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: To access content you need to add the protocol that will be used. try using file access which is typically file://<path to file>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript in the browser generally doesn't allow you to access files located on the file system, if it could, it would be a security vulnerability. The browser environment is contained in a sandbox.

However, you may want to look into using the `File API` provided by HTML5 to interact with local files.
Refer to [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) for examples and explanation on the HTML5 File  API.